# ViewPager's fakeDragBy() or setCurrentItem() doesn't snap to current item

Tags: android, gallery, android-viewpager

Resolved.  See answer marked as correct along with my comments.  Can post example code if necessary

---

I'm using the [VelocityViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969879/2157961) to implement a "fling" behavior.  There is a known behavior with it where the page doesn't snap if you drag it by a certain amount.  I'm trying to get around it with little success...

**Attempt 1**

I can get the snap action to work correctly by using `setCurrentItem`.  The caveat is that it only snaps if I call the function on an item before or after the current page, for example `setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem()+1)`

So this solution works, but it gives the user a bad user experience if I have to set the current item further than they expect it to.

***Does anyone have any advice on how I can call `setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem())` and have it actually animate/scroll/snap?***  The source implies that it should.  The [r7 code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#435) seems to always call the scroll function.

**Attempt 2**

As another test, I did many `fakeDragBy(1)` calls to drag the `ViewPager` thinking that it would snap after it reached a certain threshold, but that wasn't the case.  ***What's preventing the ViewPager from snapping?***

Below is code to reproduce this, if you're interested.  I used the same [VelocityViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969879/2157961) code with the following changes

*VelocityViewPager.java*

```
public class VelocityViewPager extends ViewPager implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // give all the events to the gesture detector. I'm returning true here so the viewpager doesn't
        // get any events at all, I'm sure you could adjust this to make that not true.
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem(), true);
            Log.d("VelocityViewPager", "Setting to item " + getCurrentItem());
        }
        return true;
    }
....
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.example.velocityviewpager;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VelocityViewPager pager = (VelocityViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 20;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                TextView view = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                view.setText("Item "+position);
                view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 10, position * 10, position * 10));
                view.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 200, 200, 200));

                container.addView(view);
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View)object);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
                return (view == o);
            }
        };
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <view
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="300dip"
            class="com.example.velocityviewpager.VelocityViewPager"
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi cheezy, any progress on this please?

Comment: I've put it on the backburner until next week.  I'll let you know if I find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround. I track what movement was done previously, and when a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` occurs I trigger a new fling. I am not sure, if it's logically correct this way (is this the good direction? and is this a good velocity for a new fling?), but I tested it, and it works:

```
private boolean isLeftDirection = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // give all the events to the gesture detector. I'm returning true here
    // so the viewpager doesn't
    // get any events at all, I'm sure you could adjust this to make that
    // not true.

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        int id = getCurrentItem();
        setCurrentItem(id, true);
        if (isLeftDirection){
            mFlingRunnable.startUsingVelocity((int) 1);
        } else {
            mFlingRunnable.startUsingVelocity((int) -1);
        }
    }
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distX,
        float distY) {
    trackMotion(-distX);
    if (distX > 0){ 
        isLeftDirection = true;}
    else{
        isLeftDirection = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  It definitely helped point me in the right direction.  I came up with a solution that enabled me to stop on the nearest page (rather than going forward or back one).  The key is that when you call `endFakeDrag()`, it will call `setCurrentItemInternal` with the `always` parameter set to true.  This will force you the ViewPager to recenter to the closest item.  I can post example code if you'd like.  But basically I call `EndFakeDrag()` if we detect `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and just ended a scroll

Comment: Can you please share the code with fakebydrag