# How do I cancel ViewPager's "snap" animation after calling endFakeDrag()?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, scroller, onfling

**Context:** I tried to implement a [flingable VelocityViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969879/6876672). The flinging motion works properly. I like that the page "snaps" to center after the flinging motion. Despite this, I've had a few issues with it so far. One issue is that the page doesn't snap to center when you drag it passed a certain amount. I've solved this issue using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900137/6876672) so this is just for context. Another issue is below...

---

**Problem:** After beginFakeDrag() -> FlingRunnable (flinging motion) -> endFakeDrag(), endFakeDrag()'s internal code "snaps" the page to center. When I try to fling again **during** the snap motion, it waits until **after** the animation completes--putting the flinging motion on queue.

How can I cancel the snap motion on touch down so that it doesn't delay the flinging motion?

---

**Attempt 1:** On touch down, I tried to beginFakeDrag() but it doesn't cancel the endFakeDrag() snap motion.

**Attempt 2:** Instead of calling endFakeDrag(), I tried to mimic the snap motion **during** fake drag so that I can implement the cancellation myself and only call endFakeDrag() when the page is already centered. I tried this via SnapRunnable using Scroller's startScroll().

This might be my best option, but I can't figure out how much distanceX to scroll to in order to center the page. I tried to look into the original ViewPager.class but the algorithms confused me and it seems to depend on more internal code that the VelocityViewPager.class can't access.