# Android: How to implement ViewPager with scroll bar?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollbar

I have a challenging problem and wanted to see if the community has some comments about its implementation.

I have a ViewPager and added 20 pages in it, and each page has a WebView. – This provides vertical page flipping between multiple websites 
It should work as a ViewPager by default but when I pinch to zoom, each page will shrink and the ViewPager will scroll like a List View.
I didn’t want to use a different view like a List View as I want a smooth transition and the two modes use the same web contents so want to avoid any construction/deconstruction that might affect a smooth transition.
I was able to implement this scrolling ViewPager with [VelocityViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969879).

What I want to do is add a scrollbar to navigate down the pages by holding and dragging a scroller, just like a PC’s behaviour – as opposed to a ListView which only shows the scrollbar but allows no interaction. I have made a custom view that looks like a scrollbar and performs a ViewPager’s fake drag as the scrollbar is moved. The problem is I can only scroll pages ViewPager is holding - so when the ViewPager keeps the whole 20 pages, it works well but If I keep 3 pages as default to make use of page recycling, it doesn’t scroll past 3. It seems as though it doesn’t create the next pages that it usually would when scrolling with your finger.

I’m not sure why ViewPager doesn’t create next pages while fake dragging. Is there anything I have to do other than beginFakeDrag(), endFakeDrag() and fakeDragBy()?
And, Is there any way I can implement this behaviour without keeping all 20 pages in ViewPager?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this code, this may be useful to you:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
      ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
      myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
     }

     private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.gallery_photo_1, R.drawable.gallery_photo_2,
       R.drawable.gallery_photo_3, R.drawable.gallery_photo_5,
       R.drawable.gallery_photo_6, R.drawable.gallery_photo_7,
       R.drawable.gallery_photo_8, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

}
```

and ViewPager class is:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Activity activity;
int imageArray[];

public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
    imageArray = imgArra;
    activity = act;
}

public int getCount() {
    return imageArray.length;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) collection.findViewById(R.id.image);
    /*
     * view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
     * LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
     */
    view.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[position]);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks mate but my question is not how to use ViewPager and Adapter. I need to make a custom ViewPager and would like to know if there's possible way to fulfill my requirement.