# Velocity View Pager setCurrentItem not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using the VelocityViewPager [found in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787287/android-velocity-based-viewpager-scrolling#answer-14969879) in order to implement a flingable ViewPager. I am trying to set the view pager to initialize by showing an element in the middle of the VelocityViewPager (the date 1970). So in the onViewCreated() of my fragment I do:

```
velocityViewPager.setCurrentItem(69);
```

A user suggested doing the following to fix this issue in the comments of the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787287/android-velocity-based-viewpager-scrolling#answer-14969879):

```
private void trackMotion(float distX) {
    final int width = getWidth();
    final int widthWithMargin = width + this.getPageMargin();
    float scrollOffset = getScrollX() - (this.getCurrentItem() * widthWithMargin);
    float scrollX = getScrollX() - distX - scrollOffset;
    ........
}
```

When I tried this, however, it did not work and I would be stuck seeing elements 68, 69, and 70 of the ViewPager because the scrollX would be stuck because the offset would "lock" the scrollX to a range.

The issue I noticed is the scrollX is initialized to 0 when it really should be a value representing position 69. I tried manually setting the scrollX in XML, setting the scrollX in Java code, and doing various offset computations to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing for a flingable view. It is definitely more painful (it required a lot of trial and error on my part) than just extending from view pager, but it gave me what I wanted. You will have to figure out a way to use the View's scrollX in order to determine what item to snap to and what to do when you reach the end or start of the view.

```
public class FlingableScroller extends View implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    public FlingableScroller(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        mScroller = new OverScroller(context);
        //This is how you "set current item" You will have to calculate INITIAL_SCROLL_X yourself
        setScrollX(INITIAL_SCROLL_X);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        animateFlingIfApplicable();
    }

    private void animateFlingIfApplicable() {
        //We have a fling only if computeScrollOffset is true.
        if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            //Flinging passed the start point so continue the fling at the end
            if (mScroller.getFinalX() == 0) {
                int velocity = getFlingVelocity();
                mScroller.forceFinished(true);
                mScroller.fling(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_X, 0, velocity / FRICTION_COEFFICIENT, 0, 0, MAXIMUM_SCROLL_X, 0, 0);
                //Flinging passed the end point so continue the fling at the start
            } else if (mScroller.getFinalX() == MAXIMUM_SCROLL_X) {
                int velocity = getFlingVelocity();
                mScroller.forceFinished(true);
                mScroller.fling(0, 0, velocity / FRICTION_COEFFICIENT, 0, 0, MAXIMUM_SCROLL_X, 0, 0);
            } else if (mScroller.getFinalX() == getScrollX() || mScroller.getCurrVelocity() == 0) {
                snapToItem();
                mScroller.forceFinished(true);
            } else {
                scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), 0);
            }
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        //This logic handles the case when you scroll pass the beginning or the end of the scroller
        if (getScrollX() > MAXIMUM_SCROLL_X) {
            scrollTo(0, 0);
        } else if (getScrollX() >= 0) {
            scrollBy(distance, 0);
        } else {
            scrollTo(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_X, 0);
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        //This is to prevent low velocity "flings"
        if (Math.abs(velocityX) < 400 * SCREEN_DENSITY) {
            return false;
        }

        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        //Define friction_coefficient to a value that gives you desirable flinging.
        mScroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), (int) -velocityX / FRICTION_COEFFICIENT, 0, 0, MAXIMUM_SCROLL_X, 0, 0);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mScroller.forceFinished(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                snapToItem();
                invalidate();
                break;
    }
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void snapToItem() {
        //The the user lifts up their finger from a scroll or when a fling finishes determine what item to snap to. See the ViewPager source code to emulate the "fake drag"
        int scrollByValue = getScrollX() / SOME_VALUE
        scrollTo(scrollByValue, 0);
    }
}
```