# Scroll more than one item in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel

I am trying to scroll more than one item in a `ViewPager` per swipe. I have implemented a carousel like `ViewPager` by setting the `PagerAdapter`'s `getPageWidth()` to return `.33f`. And I am trying to scroll 3 items per swipe. I have tried incrementing position in `ViewPager.onPageScrolled()`. But it isn't working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can ViewPager have multiple views in per page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468581/can-viewpager-have-multiple-views-in-per-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager is not the answer. You need [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) with paging. that enables you when flinging to swipe multiple pages but doesnt stop in the middle of a page.

In case u still want ViewPager - 
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787287/android-velocity-based-viewpager-scrolling)

Comment: If Viewpager stops in the middle of a page, I don't mind. I have a working version with viewpager. Can't it be done in any means with ViewPager?

Comment: It will be much easier to move to HorizontalScrollView then to change the onTouch of the ViewPager. IMO

Comment: Can you shade some light on how can I implement this with ViewPager? If I switch now, I have to change many things.